How to handle limit/block when crawling data from the Tripadvisor?
I'm working on a dissertation that requires a lot of travel reviews, so I start to use Puppeteer to scrap data from the web, but in this case, when I try to do it on tripadvisor.com, it blocks my requests. After solve Captcha; tried to run this script.
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    exacutablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
  });
  
  const page = browser.newPage();

  await page.setViewport({width: 1080, height: 1080});

  await page.goto('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g297962-d1804746-Reviews-Megasaray_Westbeach_Antalya-Antalya_Turkish_Mediterranean_Coast.html'); 

  const all_Language = await page.waitForSelector(
    '#hrReviewFilters > div.ruCQl.z > div.uqMDf.z.QfvOn.aHiYo.QJjmz > ul > li:nth-child(1) > label > span.HuTXl.q'
  );
  
  all_Languages.click();
  
})();

*https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g297962-d1804746-Reviews-Megasaray_Westbeach_Antalya-Antalya_Turkish_Mediterranean_Coast.html
This link is given for example.
This is the first part of my Javascript code where I tried to change the review languages to 'All languages'. After that, I'm going to scrape the reviews, but already at this step of the process, I have been blocked by tripadvisor.com.
I tried doing a rotation proxy to avoid being blocked but it didn't work. I'm still getting blocked on the site.
...
const proxies = [
  'http://23.29.152.34:8080',
  'http://23.29.152.77:8080',
  'http://20.72.218.43:8080',
  'http://20.37.207.8:8080',
  'http://181.129.43.3:8080',
  'http://103.36.35.135:8080',
  'http://183.89.9.82:8080',
  'http://23.29.152.76:8080'
];
...


Have you tried modifying the user agent as well as the IP? Also you're probably going to need a much larger list of proxies if you want to scrape large amounts of data quickly. Highly reccomend paying for a proxy list service, and you'll probably want them to be fully anonymous(A lot of proxies are transparent).

Oftentimes the free proxies listed online are automatically detected after a few requests. With 50-100+ high quality proxies and a collection of the same number of user agents and randomizing combinations of the user agents + IP addresses you should have better luck

Thank you for your answer. We tried this approach but they still caught us :)
